# How to load commonmark.js in a local HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, commonmark

I was following the steps and wrote a demo HTML. Here are the steps in the README of https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark.js#commonmarkjs :

> For client-side use, you can do `make dist` to produce
>   a standalone JavaScript file `js/dist/commonmark.js`,
>   suitable for linking into a web page, or fetch the latest
>   from
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jgm/commonmark.js/master/dist/commonmark.js,
>   or `bower install commonmark`.

Here is my demo HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jgm/commonmark.js/master/dist/commonmark.js"></script>
      <script>
         window.onload = function() {
             console.log(commonmark)
         }
      </script>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

Here is a JSFiddle URL for my demo: https://jsfiddle.net/y3xohp7x/

I saved this HTML locally in a file named `foo.html` and opened this local file with Firefox 55.0.1.

But if I load it with Firefox 55.0.1, I get the following errors in the console.

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jgm/commonmark.js/master/dist/commonmark.js”. foo.html:5
ReferenceError: commonmark is not defined foo.html:9:5
```

Questions:

1. Why does this error occur?
2. How can I resolve this error without having to copy `commonmark.js` to the local filesystem?
3. Is it a bug in the commonmark.js README documentation that I quoted above or is it an error in my understanding of the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Actually, there apparently is a way to do this for github content in particular: https://rawgit.com/

This website gives you a link to a version of the script that will be served with the correct MIME-type.

So this should load the script properly for you:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jgm/commonmark.js/master/dist/commonmark.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w1uvq59r/

---

**Original Answer**

The reason is that the script source is sent back with the headers:

```
"Content-Type": "text/plain"
"X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff"
```

The latter header prevents the browser from executing the script due to the fact that the content-type is not executable, like "application/javascript". Which means unfortunately there is really no way to get the script to load remotely. [Here is a thread with more information on a similar problem.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/chrome-refused-to-execute-this-javascript-file/50017#50017)

---

The only solution, as far as I can tell, is to load it locally, like so:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="path/to/the/file.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you answer all the three questions I have asked?

Comment: I edited my comment to hopefully add some clarity. May I ask why you are not able to use the script locally?

Comment: There is no particular reason to avoid using the script locally. I am just exploring the possibilities for the sake of learning. For example, if I can link directly to the GitHub URL of the script, then I don't have to worry about updating my local copy of script periodically.